# chrome.storage.sync.get returns empty object if an object passed with its key set undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension

```
await chrome.storage.sync.set({test: 25}); // set an example key
chrome.storage.sync.get({ test: undefined }).then(console.log); //outputs {}
chrome.storage.sync.get({ test: null }).then(console.log); // outputs {test: 25}
```

> An empty list or object will return an empty result object. Pass in
> null to get the entire contents of storage.

The documentation says an empty object would return an empty object but `{ test: undefined }` is not an empty object. `{ test: null }` works as expected.

Why does passing `{ test: undefined }` return an empty object for `sync.get`?

Comment: `undefined` is not JSON-compatible, so the entire key is ignored.